# How to serialize groovys LazyMap in Java

Tags: java, serialization, groovy

I use a distributed java application with some groovy scripting support. Now when it comes to serialization I will get a `NotSerializableException` for groovys `LazyMap`. I checked the source code of the LazyMap and it does not seem that something is preventing serialization. How can I use java serialization on such objects? Should I byte code manipulate or is there an easier way? Since we are talking about distributed applications one can assume that we are talking about huge amount of data and therefore I want to avoid recursively copy a LayMap into another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrap now all the possible groovy objects into a Wrapper class and use kryo inside of this class, this seems to work quite well (at least as a prototype).

```
public class Wrapper implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 889826451319869803L;
    private transient Object wrapped;

    public Wrapper() {

    }

    public Wrapper(Object wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
        Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Output output = new Output(bos);
        kryo.writeObject(output, wrapped);
        output.close();
        stream.writeObject(bos.toByteArray());
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
        byte[] bytes = (byte[]) stream.readObject();
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteInputStream(bytes, bytes.length);
        Input input = new Input(bis);
        wrapped = kryo.readObject(input, LazyMap.class);
        input.close();
    }
}
```